# Skipped 172 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, firebase

In my Java project, only user login and register, there are activities with only buttons in it. When I run the emulator for the second time, I get such a warning. When I want to go to the register page, it sends to the page with the button. Or the user login page does not open when it first opens. The alert looks like this: Skipped 172 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. I'm new to Android programming, I would appreciate it if you could help.

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.geziproject">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Geziproject">
        <activity android:name=".bos"/>
        <activity android:name=".kayitol" />
        <activity android:name=".kullanicigiris">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

*kayitol.java*

```
public class kayitol extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText txtAd, txtEmail, txtŞifre;
    private Button btnkayit;
    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    //DatabaseReference yol;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kayitol);
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        txtAd = findViewById(R.id.txtad);
        txtEmail = findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        txtŞifre = findViewById(R.id.txtŞifre);
        btnkayit = findViewById(R.id.kayit);

        btnkayit.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String email = txtEmail.getText().toString();
            String pwd = txtŞifre.getText().toString();
            if (email.isEmpty()) {
                txtEmail.setError("Lütfen email giriniz");
                txtEmail.requestFocus();
            } else if (pwd.isEmpty()) {
                txtŞifre.setError("Lütfen şifre giriniz");
                txtŞifre.requestFocus();
            } else if (email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(kayitol.this, "Bu alanlar boş bırakılamaz", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (!(email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty())) {
                mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pwd).addOnCompleteListener(kayitol.this, task -> {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(kayitol.this, "Kayıt başarısız,tekrar deneyiniz", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(kayitol.this, bos.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(kayitol.this, "Hata oluştu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

*kullanicigiris.java*

```
public class kullanicigiris extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btngiris;
    Button btnkayit;
    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private EditText txtad;
    private EditText txtemail;
    private EditText txtsifre;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kullanicigiris);
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        Button btngiris = findViewById(R.id.giris);
        Button btnkayit = findViewById(R.id.kayit);

        txtad = findViewById(R.id.txtad);
        txtemail = findViewById(R.id.txtemaili);
        txtsifre = findViewById(R.id.txtŞifre);
        
        mAuthListener = firebaseAuth -> {
            FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (mFirebaseUser != null) {
                Toast.makeText(kullanicigiris.this, "giriş yaptın", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(kullanicigiris.this, bos.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(kullanicigiris.this, "lütfen giriş yapın", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };

        btngiris.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String email = txtemail.getText().toString();
            String pwd = txtsifre.getText().toString();
            if (email.isEmpty()) {
                txtemail.setError("Lütfen email giriniz");
                txtemail.requestFocus();
            } else if (pwd.isEmpty()) {
                txtsifre.setError("Lütfen şifre giriniz");
                txtsifre.requestFocus();
            } else if (email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(kullanicigiris.this, "Bu alanlar boş bırakılamaz", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (!(email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty())) {
                mFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pwd).addOnCompleteListener(kullanicigiris.this, task -> {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(kullanicigiris.this, "Giriş  başarısız ,tekrar deneyiniz", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        txtad.setText("");
                        txtemail.setText("");
                        txtsifre.setText("");
                        startActivity(new Intent(kullanicigiris.this, bos.class));
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(kullanicigiris.this, "Hata oluştu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        btnkayit.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent i = new Intent(kullanicigiris.this, kayitol.class);
            startActivity(i);
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

    }
}
```

*bos.java*

```
public class bos extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bos);
    }
}
```

run:

```
12/07 16:40:12: Launching 'app' on Pixel.
Install successfully finished in 2 s 552 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.geziproject/com.example.geziproject.kullanicigiris" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 7342 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/ple.geziprojec: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
I/ple.geziprojec: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
W/ple.geziprojec: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
W/ple.geziprojec: Verification of boolean com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailabilityLight.isPlayServicesPossiblyUpdating(android.content.Context, int) took 251.962ms (19.84 bytecodes/s) (776B approximate peak alloc)
W/ple.geziprojec: Verification of com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.app.Activity) took 120.192ms (316.16 bytecodes/s) (1400B approximate peak alloc)
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/ple.geziprojec: Verification of void com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.<init>(com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager, com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi) took 115.333ms (945.09 bytecodes/s) (3688B approximate peak alloc)
W/ple.geziprojec: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ple.geziprojec: Verification of void com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.onConnected(android.os.Bundle) took 141.826ms (246.78 bytecodes/s) (1264B approximate peak alloc)
W/ple.geziprojec: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10153; state: ENABLED
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xeaedfd50, tid 7393
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xeaeded90: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xeaeded90: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xeb222df0) (first time)
I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xeaedfb20, tid 7393
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
    allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3fcf6d000 size 0x2000
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=976ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=1293927629619, Vsync=1293977629617, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=1293986896900, AnimationStart=1293986963100, PerformTraversalsStart=1293987049900, DrawStart=1294410491800, SyncQueued=1294418169100, SyncStart=1294436241500, IssueDrawCommandsStart=1294436512100, SwapBuffers=1294778679200, FrameCompleted=1294922281100, DequeueBufferDuration=187900, QueueBufferDuration=733800, GpuCompleted=0, 
I/Choreographer: Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, frames being skipped at an amount under 200 or so tends to simply be lag on your emulator. This is expected; emulators are quite slow. In your current state, this is probably a problem you can safely ignore.

You could close other unnecessary programs on your computer to see if it gets better. You probably will skip a few frames no matter what, but it's generally fine.

This problem is only a serious issue if the number of skipped frames becomes large enough that it seriously affects user experiences on actual hardware. That would be in the range of 300+ frames

For detailed information, look at [Android UI : Fixing skipped frames](https://vaibhavtolia.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/79/)